# R- how to dynamically name data frames?

Tags: r, variables, dynamic, dataframe

I have two types of files in my directory. Each type has either the text "Drug_Rep" in it or if its not there it means its a control file.
Drug data has replicates which can vary in number and so does the control.
I am reading the files in a for loop as follows.
I want to name my dataframes as X_Drug_Rep1 and then the next as X_Drug_Rep2 and so on...and save the dataframe for further processing.
Do the same for controls...X_CONTROL_Rep1...X_CONTROL_Rep2...and so on.
What is the syntax to save my data into dataframes because i need to do some merges and calculations later on the drug replicate dataframes and controls separately. 
paste on the left side of assignment does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
for (f in 1:length(fileList)){
    fileName <- fileList[f]
    X <-read.xls(fileName)

    if(regexpr("Drug_Rep", fileName)[1]>0){
      print("DRUG")
      print(fileName)
      paste(X_Drug_Rep,i)<-X
      i=i+1
    }
    else{
      print("CONTROL")
      print(fileName)
      paste(X_CONTROL,j)<-X
      j=j+1
    }
  }
```

Comment: this gets asked a lot. The technical answer is to use `assign` but a preferred approach is to build a list (two in your case.)

Comment: i did click on the link but still i am not able to get the assign syntax right...is this what i do: assign(paste(X_Drug_Rep,i, sep='_'),i)

Comment: `assign(paste("X_Drug_Rep", i, sep = '_'), X)`

Comment: thanks! i do the following:assign(paste("X_Drug_Rep", i, sep = '_'), X) as you suggested but how can i access my new dataframe called X_Drug_Rep_1

Comment: `X_Drug_Rep_1` is an object so you can just access it like that, by typing `X_Drug_Rep_1`. If you mean how can you access it via a variable like `i <- 1`, this also gets asked a lot. The technical answer is to use `get` but a preferred approach is to have all of your objects in a list to start with. Hence my recommendation again: use a list!

Comment: when i type print(X_Drug_Rep_1), i get the error: Error in print(X_Drug_Rep_1) : object 'X_Drug_Rep_1' not found...so this is what i was asking. The reason i want X_Drug_Rep_1,X_Drug_Rep_2,X_Drug_Rep_3 is that i will do a merge on my dataframes later in the code.Thanks

Comment: As mentioned above, you _can_ use `assign` for this purpose but you _should not_. You can assign names to a list _after_ it's been constructed via `names(myList) <- ...`. This is much clearer, less error prone, and will result in much shorter code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

OP is really struggling so instead of a long comment, I'll show him here. Don't care if this gets closed.

The *technical* (don't do that answer) would be to use `assign`:

```
i <- 1
j <- 1
for (f in 1:length(fileList)){
    fileName <- fileList[f]
    X <-read.xls(fileName)

    if(grepl("Drug_Rep", fileName)) {
      print("DRUG")
      print(fileName)
      assign(paste("X_Drug_Rep", i, sep = '_'), X)
      i <- i+1
    } else {
      print("CONTROL")
      print(fileName)
      assign(paste("X_CONTROL", i, sep = '_'), X)
      j <- j+1
    }
  }
```

But as we recommended, you should use lists instead. Using a `for` loop, it would look like this:

```
X_Drug_Rep <- list()
X_CONTROL  <- list()
i <- 1
j <- 1
for (f in 1:length(fileList)){
    fileName <- fileList[f]
    X <-read.xls(fileName)

    if(grepl("Drug_Rep", fileName)) {
      print("DRUG")
      print(fileName)
      X_Drug_Rep[[i]] <- X
      i <- i+1
    } else {
      print("CONTROL")
      print(fileName)
      X_CONTROL[[j]] <- X
      j <- j+1
    }
  }
```

Finally, how your code would look like without a `for` loop:

```
drug.rep.files <- grep("Drug_Rep", fileList, value = TRUE)
control.files  <- grep("Drug_Rep", fileList, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)

X_Drug_Rep <- lapply(drug.rep.files, read.xls)
X_CONTROL  <- lapply(control.files, read.xls)
```

Much shorter, no?! Again, this creates two lists. For example, instead of `X_Drug_Rep_1`, you would access the first Drug_Rep item by doing `X_Drug_Rep[[1]]`.