# Subset datasets by variable before using expand.grid to calculate distance matrix

Tags: r

I have two datasets. One dataset has about ~30k rows, and the second dataset has ~60k rows.  The smaller dataset (`df1`) has a unique identifier (`upc`), which is critical to my analysis.

The larger dataset (`df2`) does *not* have this unique identifier, but it does have a descriptive variable (`product_title`) that can be matched with a similar description variable in `df1` and used to infer the unique identifier.

I am trying to keep things simple, so I used `expand.grid`.

```
df1_titles<-unique(df1$product_title) # List of 30k titles
df2_titles<-unique(df2$product_title) # List of 60k titles
r<- expand.grid(df1_titles,df2_titles) # Distance matrix 
names(r) <- c("df1_titles","df2_titles") 
r$dist <- stringdist(r$df1_titles,r$df2_titles, method="jw") # Calculate distance
r<-r[order(r$dist),] 
r<-r[!duplicated(r$df1_titles),] 
r<-subset(r,dist<.10)
```

Unfortunately, R is struggling to expand such a large grid. So, I had the idea to use a second variable (`c1`) in both datasets to constrain the `expand.grid` to similar items. Let's assume the values for `category` are the same for both datasets.

While I know it's [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255851/r-how-to-dynamically-name-data-frames) [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081982/how-to-assign-values-to-dynamic-names-variables) to create dataframes using a loop, I didn't have a better idea for how to subset the data to `expand.grid` so I tried this approach anyways:

```
categories<-c("Beauty","Personal Care","Grocery","Household Essentials") # Variable with categories to subset

for (i in seq_along(categories)) {
  df1_sub<-subset(wmt,category==categories[i])
  df2_sub<-subset(m,category==categories[i])
  df1_titles<-unique(df1_sub$product_title)
  df2_titles<-unique(df2_sub$product_title)
  ### HOW DO I CREATE A LIST/GRID DYNAMICALLY? ### <-expand.grid(df1_titles,df2_titles)
}
```

After creating these grids, the plan would be to grab the unique identifier `upc` from `df1` and assign it to matches in `df2` before consolidating the datasets.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, and hope that identifying a better way to reduce `data.frames` to relevant subsets before using `expand.grid` will be helpful to others!

```
dput(sample_n(subset(df1,select=c(product_title,c1)),50)) structure(list(product_title = c("Sriracha Hot Chili Sauce Single Packets 25 Count .25 oz each (3 Items Per Order, not per case)",  "Duncan Hines Double Fudge Decadent Brownie Mix 17.6 oz by Duncan Hines",  "Mikee Tropical Teriyaki Sauce, 20 oz, (Pack of 12)", "NESQUIK Strawberry Low Fat Milk 6-8 fl. oz. Bottles",  "Dove Nutritive Solutions Conditioner, Coconut & Hydration 12 oz (Pack of 12)",  "FLORATA 24\" Long Straight Velcro Wrap Around Ponytail Hair Extensions",  "Bing Cherries, Dried (16 oz, ZIN: 527111) - 3-Pack", "San-J Tamari Brown Sesame Crackers, 3.7 oz (Pack of 12)",  "PERDUE HARVESTLAND Breaded Chicken Breast Nugget (22 oz.)",  "Fray Bentos Just Chicken Pie (425g) - Pack of 6", "Product of Thomas Coffee Regular Roast, Portion Packs (64 ct.) - Ground Coffee [Bulk Savings]", "Bombay Basmati Rice White, 2 LB (Pack of 12)", "Herbs for Kids, Sugar Free Elderberry Syrup, Cherry-Berry Flavor, 4 fl oz (pack of 3)",  "Grain Millers BG13916 Grain Millers Rolled Oats No. 5 - 1x50LB",  "Tuning Fork C 512 C512 SURGICAL MEDICAL INSTRUMENTS NEW", "Garnier Fructis Style Pure Clean Finishing Paste, All Hair Types, 2 oz. (Packaging May Vary) (Pack of 8)",  "Stretch Island Organic Fruit Strips Grape -- 6 Pocket-Sized Fruit Strips pack of 6",  "Torani Cinnamon Syrup 750ml", "JFC Nori Maki Arare Crackers 3 oz each (6 Items Per Order)",  "FLORATA Ponytail Buns Wrap Bun Chignon Hair Extensions Wavy Curly Wedding Donut Hair Extensions Hairpiece Wig",  "Kenra Platinum Hot Spray #20 8oz, PACK OF 8", "GBS Red and Black Shampoo Scalp Massage Brushes Plus 1 Soft Pocket Brush Made In USA 3 Pack Promotes Healthy Hair Growth Compliments Any Shampoo and Conditioner",  "Clairol Professional Creme Permanent Developer - 20 volume (Size : 2 oz)",  "Garnier Nutrisse Ultra Color Permanent Haircolor R3 Light Intense Auburn 1.0 ea(pack of 12)",  "Kemps Swiss Style Chocolate Low Fat Milk, 1 gal", "Aussie Kids 3n1 Shampoo, Conditioner, & Bodywash with Pump Coral Reef Cupcake 29.2 oz.(pack of 4)",  "Dequmana Gordal Olives, 12 Oz", "Duncan Hines Caramel Creamy Home-Style Frosting 16 Oz Canister",  "Goya Goya Mole, 9 oz", "Fruit Roll-Ups Fruit Flavored Snacks Variety Pack (Pack of 16)",  "Wild Huckleberry Mountain Huckleberry Barbecue Sauce", "La Flor Spicy Hot Seasoned Salt, 13 oz",  "Clairol Nice n Easy Hair Color #79 Dark Brown, UK Loving Care (Pack of 3) + Beyond BodiHeat Patch, 1 Ct",  "White Vinegar Liquid ''1 gallon, 4 Count, Liquid''", "Metallic Gold Dried Canella Berries - 6 oz Bunch",  "La Flor Adobo All-Purpose Seasoning, 13 oz", "Marlos Bakeshop Marlos Bakeshop Biscotti, 1.25 oz",  "Sam's Choice Frozen Burrito Bowl, Fajita Vegetable, 12.5 oz",  "Conchita guava marmalade 14.1 oz Pack of 3", "HC Industries Kids Organics Kids Organics Shampoo, 12 oz",  "6 Pack - Head & Shoulders Full & Thick 2-in-1 Anti-Dandruff Shampoo + Conditioner 32.1 oz",  "Ice Breakers, Wintergreen Mints Tin, 1.5 Oz (Pack of 8)", "Mason Pearson - Boar Bristle & Nylon - Medium Junior Military Nylon & Bristle Hair Brush (Dark Ruby) -1pc",  "Dove Nutritive Solutions Revival Cleansing Shampoo, 20.4 oz",  "Boston's Best 12 Ct Jamaican Me Crazy", "Ultimate Baker Edible Glitter Mix It Up (1x3oz)",  "Nori Maki Arare Rice Crackers with Seaweed 5 oz per Pack (1 Pack)",  "H&S 2in1 MENS REFRESH POO 13.5oz-Pack of 5", "Keebler Club Mini Crackers, Multi-Grain, 11 Ounce (Pack of 20)",  "Briess Sparkling Amber Liquid Malt Extract (30 Pound Pail)"), 
    c1 = c("Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Personal Care", 
    "Beauty", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", 
    "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Grocery", 
    "Grocery", "Grocery", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty", 
    "Beauty", "Grocery", "Beauty", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", 
    "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Beauty", "Grocery", "Grocery", 
    "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Personal Care", 
    "Beauty", "Grocery", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Grocery", "Grocery", 
    "Grocery", "Beauty", "Grocery", "Grocery")), row.names = c(16523L,  111871L, 28667L, 32067L, 8269L, 11076L, 50328L, 47200L, 99415L,  100031L, 39011L, 104854L, 29516L, 104643L, 3486L, 9689L, 52157L,  28995L, 47000L, 10895L, 3035L, 4992L, 3589L, 4276L, 32212L, 6055L,  22991L, 110279L, 27436L, 52282L, 14879L, 25710L, 6989L, 30133L,  51068L, 25490L, 45685L, 99073L, 18547L, 4991L, 5792L, 36241L,  10237L, 1430L, 40383L, 112458L, 46261L, 5875L, 46597L, 108099L ), class = "data.frame")

dput(sample_n(subset(df2,select=c(product_title,c1)),50))
structure(list(product_title = c("Drive Medical Heavy Duty Bariatric Plastic Seat Transfer Bench", 
"Always Pure & Clean Ultra Thin Feminine Pads With Wings, Super Long", 
"Patriot Candles Jar Candle Apple Clove Red", "Nature's Bounty Cardio-Health Probiotic Capsules", 
"Finest Nutrition Biotin Plus Keratin", "Dr. Scholl's DuraGel Corn Remover", 
"Humm Coconut Lime Kombucha 14 oz", "OneTouch Ultra Blue Test Strips", 
"Kellogg's Rice Krispies Treats Bars M&M's", "Westbrae Natural Organic Chili Beans", 
"Neutrogena Rapid Clear Acne Eliminating Spot Treatment Gel - 0.5 fl oz", 
"Harris Bed Bug Killer", "Quart Storage Bags - 80ct - Up&Up cent (Compare to Ziploc Storage Bags)", 
"Care Free Curl Gold Instant Curl Activator", "Purple Dessert Plate", 
"Wexford Big Bubble Plastic Mailer 2", "L'Oreal Paris Advanced Haircare Total Repair Extreme Emergency Recovery Mask", 
"Soap & Glory Spectaculips Matteallic Lip Cream Bronze Girl,Bronze Girl", 
"No7 Instant Results Purifying Heating Mask - 2.5oz", "NuMe Classic Curling Wand", 
"Revlon ColorSilk ColorStay Nourishing Conditioner Glowing Blonde", 
"Weiman Lemon Oil Furniture Polish Lemon", "Dunkin' Donuts Ground Coffee Hazelnut", 
"CocoaVia Cocoa Extract 375mg, Capsules", "Triple Paste AF Antifungal Ointment", 
"Welch's Halloween Fruit Snacks 0.5oz 28 ct", "Studio 35 Purifying Natural Facial Wipes", 
"Magnum Double Raspberry Mini Ice Cream Bars - 3ct", "CHI Twisted Fabric Finishing Paste", 
"Creme Of Nature Argan Oil Intensive Conditioning Hair Treatment", 
"Exergen Temporal Artery Thermometer", "Tolerex Formulated Liquid Diet Elemental Powder 6 Pack Unflavored", 
"Gerber Nature Select 2nd Foods Nutritious Dinner Baby Food Chicken Noodle", 
"Abreva Cold Sore Cream", "Super Macho Vitality and Stamina Dietary Supplement Softgel", 
"M&M's Peanut Chocolates Halloween Ghoul's Mix - 3.27oz", "TruMoo protein milk cookies n' cream - 14 fl oz", 
"DISNEY 25 Inch Plush Toy Assorted", "Beauty Infusion HYDRATING Manuka Honey & Collagen Sheet Mask", 
"Edge Shave Gel, Twin Pack Sensitive Skin", "Haribo Sour Gold Bears Resealable Stand Up Pouch Pineapple", 
"Jarrow Formulas Extra Virgin Coconut Oil, 1000mg, Softgels", 
"Bliss Pore Patrol Oil-Free Hydrator with Willow Bark - 1.7oz", 
"Airheads Candy Bites Watermelon", "Thrive Market Organic Sprouted Quinoa", 
"Garnier Fructis Curl Stretch Loosening Pudding", "Systane Nighttime Lubricant Eye Ointment", 
"SOHO Resort Organizer", "Enfamil Enfacare Lipil Infant Formula Powder", 
"Fancy Feast Flaked Gourmet Cat Food Tuna"), c1 = c("Home Health Care Solutions", 
"Personal Care", "Household Essentials", "Vitamin & Supplements", 
"Vitamin & Supplements", "Personal Care", "Grocery", "Home Health Care Solutions", 
"Grocery", "Grocery", "Beauty", "Household Essentials", "Household Essentials", 
"Beauty", "Household Essentials", "Household Essentials", "Beauty", 
"Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Beauty", "Household Essentials", 
"Grocery", "Vitamin & Supplements", "Personal Care", "Grocery", 
"Beauty", "Grocery", "Beauty", "Personal Care", "Personal Care", 
"Home Health Care Solutions", "Grocery", "Personal Care", "Vitamin & Supplements", 
"Grocery", "Grocery", "Baby, Kids & Toys", "Beauty", "Personal Care", 
"Grocery", "Vitamin & Supplements", "Beauty", "Grocery", "Grocery", 
"Beauty", "Personal Care", "Beauty", "Grocery", "Household Essentials"
)), row.names = c(39590L, 6987L, 13810L, 19403L, 26966L, 446L, 
41599L, 28238L, 7622L, 19653L, 16458L, 18164L, 738L, 19819L, 
43731L, 13310L, 17113L, 29729L, 29725L, 38903L, 25464L, 10048L, 
42932L, 41179L, 37568L, 5830L, 14276L, 20526L, 31614L, 20119L, 
40084L, 25978L, 1573L, 25121L, 3660L, 8850L, 10201L, 43313L, 
17973L, 40423L, 10299L, 37320L, 32177L, 18491L, 32860L, 30439L, 
24518L, 21579L, 24597L, 14687L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You might try looking at the **fuzzyjoin** package and trying to join on some measure of string distance. I haven't used it with data quite that large, though.

Comment: @CPak just spotted an error in how a column in `df1` was labeled. Fixed now - let me know if you still have issues?

Comment: Still getting an error - `Error: unexpected symbol in "dput(sample_n(subset(df1,select=c(product_title,c1)),50)) structure` - `df2` seems ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is good. One realization of it then would be

```
df2$upc <- NA
for(ctg in unique(df2$c1)) {
  d <- stringdistmatrix(df1[df1$c1 == ctg, "product_title"], df2[df2$c1 == ctg, "product_title"], method = "jw")
  fuzz <- apply(d, 2, min)
  passThr <- fuzz < 0.1
  df2$fuzz[df2$c1 == ctg] <- fuzz
  df2$upc[df2$c1 == ctg][passThr] <- df1[df1$c1 == ctg, "upc"][apply(d, 2, which.min)][passThr]
}
```

So, for each line in `df2`, it gets assigned a `upc` value from `df1` whose `product.title_r` has the smallest distance from the corresponding `product_title` from `df2`. How well this works will depend on the number of categories, `length(unique(df2$c1))`. The more of them, the faster the loop.

Comment: This is a really elegant approach, and will work well with a multi-level taxonomy like I have! Could you incorporate a "max.dist" filter into your example? I would like to determine some threshold (as in my example, `dist<.10`) to ensure the matches are sufficiently high quality.

Comment: @roody, you mean to do the assignment when the distance is below 0.1 and no assignment otherwise?

Comment: Yes - exactly. in my code it is `r<-subset(r,dist<.10)` after calculating `string.dist`

Comment: One very dense follow-up that I just can't figure out. How would I create a new variable with the value of `passThr`? The reason why I ask is because my dataset seems to be including only perfect matches, so I want to analyze if I've done something wrong.

Comment: @roody, I suppose you mean a single long vector for all categories at the same time rather for individual categories, as it is now. In that case, after running the whole loop looking at `!is.na(df2$upc)` gives that. Those values of `df2$upc` that are `NA` weren't assigned anything as nothing passed the threshold, which is equivalent to knowing all `passThr`'s.

Comment: I may not have referenced the right variable then. What I meant is that there will be varying quality of fuzzy matches when filtering for a certain threshold (`<0.1`). Even within the same category, some matches will be exact (`0`) whereas others will be fuzzy (`>0`). It would be helpful to calculate the distribution of "fuzziness" (i.e. % of matches that are exact, % that are just barely under the threshold) by capturing as an additional variable in `df2`.

Comment: @roody, right, that's what I suspected, but then it's not exactly `passThr` what you want since it's a logical vector. See the update; `fuzz` will contain all the distances, including those above the threshold. I can't really test it since your subsample is too small but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider extending your `expand.grid` approach and build a list of data frames of nested merged elements. Then row bind all at once outside of loop.

```
# Variable with categories to subset
categories <- c("Beauty", "Personal Care", "Grocery", "Household Essentials") 

df_list <- vector("list", length = length(categories))

for (i in seq_along(categories)) {
  df1_sub <- subset(wmt, category == categories[i])
  df2_sub <- subset(m, category == categories[i])
  df1_titles <- unique(df1_sub$product_title)
  df2_titles <- unique(df2_sub$product_title)

  ### HOW DO I CREATE A LIST/GRID DYNAMICALLY?     
  r <-  expand.grid(df1_titles=df1_titles, df2_titles=df2_titles, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)     

  r$dist  <- stringdist(r$df1_titles, r$df2_titles, method="jw") 
  r <- r[order(r$dist),] 
  r <- r[!duplicated(r$df1_titles),] 
  r <- subset(r, dist<.10)

  # ASSIGN NESTED MERGE
  df_list[i] = merge(merge(r, df1, by.x="df1_title", by.y="product_title"), 
                     df2, by.x="df2_title", by.y="product_title")
}

# ROW BIND ALL DF ELEMENTS
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```